# Get element with a certain value in a stringified data attribute

Tags: jquery

Example:

```
<div data-object="{ 'foo' : 123 }"></div>
<div data-object="{ 'foo' : 456 }"></div>
```

What would be the fastest way to find the div with foo value 123? At the moment im looping through the divs, converting the stringified object to a js object and check if the foo value is equal to 123? Can this be done without a loop? Thanks

Comment: Even if you can't avoid the loop couldn't use regex instead of converting the object? I guess somehow/somewhere you can't avoid the loop but you may boost your performance avoiding parsing.

Comment: @alex Why is it an invalid attribute? I thought data-XYZ were valid HTML 5 attributes, where XYZ is any text string.

Comment: @harag Because the original post used `"` as the attribute value delimiter and then used `"` internally for the JSON object's keys. Which, BTW, only `"` is *valid* for JSON according to the spec, so the edit has produced invalid JSON.

Comment: @alex Thanks for pointing out it was the `original` post, I've only seen the edited version and it looked right to me. As for the `"` for JSON, that is new to me so thanks for pointing that out as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

```
var divs = $("div").filter(function() {
    var data = $.parseJSON($(this).data("object"));
    return data.foo == 123;
});
```

This does still use a loop internally though.

Comment: Not really. A loop is unavoidable in this case due to the requirement to check the value of the `data` attribute of each div. Neither method will be prohibitively slow though.

Comment: Thanks, im developing for ie7, thats why im asking >(

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery selector

```
 function getdiv(id) {
              var divs = $('div[data-bh="{"foo":' + id + '}"]');
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to parseJson, this should work

```
var divs = $("div").filter(function() {return $(this).data("object").foo == 123;});
```

read towards the end to see more examples, http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/03/find-jquery-bug-5-defective-data.html

but as @Rory Mentioned, this does use loop internally

Comment: That will always result in an empty collection. Use `return` and `==`.